# PHP shell_exec with python naoqi: "qimessaging.socketcache: No more endpoints available after filtering"

Tags: php, python, robot, nao-robot

I can't seem to get my python script to work when I execute it in PHP with shell_exec

I am using the virtual robot in choregraphe

Here is my code:
PHP

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python test.py");
$output = shell_exec ($command);
echo $output;
```

Python:

```
from naoqi import ALProxy
import os,sys
import motion

#import qi.logging
#qi.logging.setLevel(qi.logging.FATAL)

pFractionMaxSpeed=0.4
mp = ALProxy("ALMotion", "127.0.0.1",51712)
JointName = JointNames = ["LShoulderRoll","LShoulderPitch","LElbowYaw","LElbowRoll","LHand"]
Arm1 = [90,0,-90,-85,90]
Arm1 = [ x * motion.TO_RAD for x in Arm1]
mp.post.angleInterpolationWithSpeed(JointNames, Arm1, pFractionMaxSpeed)
```

If I just run the python through cmd, then it works fine and makes the robot move.

I think it has something to do with that it is run as the www-data user and it messes the naoqi modules up (or something along those lines): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181601/using-shell-exec-or-exec-as-a-different-unix-user)

I am just not sure how to do it in windows with XAMPP or WAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that your www-data user does not have access to port 51712 (or whichever port Choregraphe's virtual nao is using - it may change between sessions, have you checked that?). Maybe you can try running `telnet 127.0.0.1 51712` from your PHP code - if that doesn't work, qimessaging won't be able to connect to that port either.

Comment: I tested it out with an actual nao robot on port 9559 and it works fine. I couldn't get the telnet command to work on windows. But since it worked with the actual robot, I am guessing that the www-data user does not have access to the virtual robot port

Comment: OK; did you check that the virtual robot's port didn't change? I think it changes each time you close and open Choregraphe.

Comment: Yes. The port stays the same. I tested the python script normally, and then I tested it with shell_exec. When I test the python normally it works, but with shell_exec it gives that error